# Why does Stack Overflow have a different upper interface?

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface, top-bar

Looking at most sites, I noticed something a bit weird. Stack Overflow has a different layout for their upper interface (which personally I find unique and easy to use).

On most of the sites I see:

```
| SE logo & Sites dropdown | Inbox | Achievements | --- | Profile | Help | Searchbar |
| Sitename | --- | Questions, Tags, Users, Badges, Unanswered | Ask Question |
```

On Stack Overflow:

```
| SO logo | Questions etc. | Searchbar | Profile | Achievements | Inbox | Help | Sites dropdown |
```

I have two questions,

1. Why does SO have such a format unlike the rest?
2. Are there any other sites that have a unique upper interface?

Comment: Stack Overflow hasn't had the new top-bar for long. It's eventually supposed to be deployed/mirrored on other sites, but the team has a few more things to sort out before they do that.

Comment: See [Top Navigation Update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update) and the [top-bar tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/top-bar) on Meta Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6):

Stack Overflow's unique navigation bar is an updated interface which began testing on [February 13, 2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343653/3357935). **This updated interface is currently only available on Stack Overflow, but will [soon be applied to the entire Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network).**

For a detailed explanation, see *[Top Navigation Update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update)* on Meta Stack Overflow and [*How Stack Overflow Redesigned the Top Navigation*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/14/why-stack-overflow-redesigned-the-top-navigation/) on the Stack Overflow blog.

Comment: The top nav has been rolled into all Stack Overflow language sites, [pt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [es](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), [ru](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), [ja](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Top bar updates are coming to the rest of the Stack Exchange network in the next couple weeks (Sept 2017). [Check the details here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network).