# Top bar missing on stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, top-bar, stackexchange.com

The top bar seems to have disappeared on stackexchange.com ...

[image]

The plain text links are still there and the markup looks correct, the CSS just seems to be missing. The nav items still work too but are similarly not styled. This is my inbox:

[image]

I've reproduced on a bunch of browsers on a few different devices.

I'd guess it's something to do with [the new top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300829/307988) being rolled out.

Comment: Lol, two minutes apart.