# Sticky top-bar across all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

So the new top bar is rolling out across SE. Well, kinda; SO's top bar is still completely fundamentally different, with a different color, the icons in slightly different places, and so forth.

But the difference that annoys me the most is that the SE top-bar is not sticky. The SO top bar is sticky by default; the SE one doesn't even have an *option* to be sticky.

The whole point of expanding the top-bar to other SE sites is to make the sites all consistent with one another. But for those of us who use SO primarily, there's no consistency. On one site, we have instant access to our "inbox", network sites, and so forth. On every other site, you have to scroll up to the top of the page to see that.

Could we make the SE top bar at least be able to share the same *position* as the SO top bar? It doesn't have to be the default, but having the option for consistency would be nice.

Comment: This is [tag:status-review] on the featured thread: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301030/284336

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: That was not a feature request.

Comment: I'm currently using a Stylish sheet that only consists of `.top-bar { position: fixed }` and it works well. So it's clearly designed in a way that makes it easily stickable...

Comment: @animuson that's not the point. Point is that it's already sticky on SO. So why not just make it consistent?

Comment: @NicolBolas historical mistake. It's dupe target of countless feature requests asking the same. Fixed now.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd My point is it wouldn't take much development effort to do it.

Comment: @animuson as someone from the inside, you know that "wouldn't take much development effort to do it" isn't always a factor. Trivial requests sometimes take years to be done, if at all. Someone in the team must first want this to be done. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: But the situation is different; we just got a redesign of the top bar. So it's not a duplicate of previous feature requests. It is a duplicate of what Catija linked to. My point is that you're linking to the wrong dupe-target.

Comment: @Catija how so?? There's even "(optional)" in the title of that old request. The request asks for the exact top bar that is currently on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Catija the look of the top bar doesn't matter, the request just asks to make it sticky, and make this optional i.e. user can choose whether to have it sticky or not.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: The request is to make it sticky *because it's new*. And it's new to match the SO top bar... which can be sticky. If you can't see the difference between that question and this one... well, there's nothing more to be said.