# Can I please have the option to sticky my top bar wherever I want?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, top-bar

With the new top bar design, Stack Overflow was given the option to make the top bar sticky so that when you scroll down the page, it's still around. Like this:

[image: Top bar sticking to top of page on Meta Stack Overflow]

This should be an option everywhere, not only on Stack Overflow.

I don't use SO or MSO very often but I've really come to appreciate this feature. It makes it really easy to get back to the front page of the site... granted, on Stack Overflow that's easy since instead of the "Stack Exchange" link in the left corner, it's the link to the front page but this is (with one extra click) still possible using the drop down menu anywhere else:

[image: Right corner hamburger menu with site selector dropped down to reveal site link to homepage]

The first link in the right corner site selector drop down goes to that same place. Using this would still take me less time/effort than scrolling back up the full length of the page to get to the top bar or site banner.

You might say... "Why don't you use page up or home to get to the top of the page?" Well, sure... if I'm done and just want the links, I can do that (assuming I remember the key combos on my laptop). But sometimes I actually *want* the links in the top bar. I'm a bit of a meta junky, so having easy access to the privileges, badges, help center, etc... links quickly and easily *without losing my place on the page* would be a big boon to me.

There are some similar requests for this:

Back in September, 2017 when the new top bar was first announced, a request was made on that announcement post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301030/284336

It has a [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag but that's it. I'm posting this as a standalone request because... well... it's been 6-8 months and I'm going out on a limb to say it's fair game to make this an official request that's more easily found by the DAG team.

Also back in September, this was requested on its own but was closed as a duplicate of the master question: [Sticky top-bar across all Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301082/sticky-top-bar-across-all-stack-exchange-sites) There's even a comment from [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson) implying that this might be pretty easily changed:

> I'm currently using a Stylish sheet that only consists of .top-bar { position: fixed } and it works well. So it's clearly designed in a way that makes it easily stickable... – animuson♦

So... Can this please be implemented as an option everywhere?

Comment: "having easy access to the privileges, badges, help center" - not to mention your inbox.

Comment: From the text just in this question, I can't tell what you're actually asking for. I think you tried to make a pun out of your question title, but it just makes it confusing, without clarifying it in your question text. "Sticking" something often means putting it somewhere. Without stating clearly in your question text what it is you want (you talk around it), the title can be read to mean that you wan to put the topbar anywhere you choose. After reading a few times, I *think* you're asking to be able to make the topbar sticky on any site, but it would *really* help if you clearly stated that.

Comment: @Makyen Combine the first sentence and the last and I'm not quite sure how it's unclear.

Comment: I *know* that users tend to dislike new features, and changes take time to get used to. But for *me* having that black top bar follow me whenever I scroll down is unnerving and reeks of narcissism. I don't need my avatar to shadow me, and the icons on the far left side are not that important. If I were a member of twenty or more SE sites then using the hamburger icon would make switching sites quicker.

Comment: If the sticky top bar is here to stay than I'd prefer to have an icon on the top bar that automatically takes me back to the main page (i.e. new/active questions page). This does not mean I want to squish valuable screen space by adding the left navigation margin. The top bar has more than enough space for another icon. EDIT I have discovered that I can [unstick](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/223820) the sticky bar. Yesss.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's configurable on your profile settings page. You can turn it off.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting today, the sticky topbar is [available network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312501/new-global-preferences-keyboard-shortcuts-and-sticky-topbar).

Comment: Too bad I don't have the option to disable it on sites where I don't have an account.

Comment: Random thought: sites without account should apply Meta SE configuration (or some custom config), not the default.