# Why is the top bar now sticky for everyone, and the preference to disable it removed from user preferences?

Tags: support, bug, top-bar

Ever since the redesign of the topbar with the option for it to be sticky (i.e. to stay visible as you scroll), I've had it not sticky. About five to ten minutes ago, I noticed that all of a sudden, my topbar was sticky. (And on pages kept open previously, on rev 2021.8.24.40058, it's not.)

As of rev 2021.8.25.40066, it's now (annoyingly) sticky, and I do not see an option in /users/settings to change it.

[image: screenshot of the sticky topbar halfway down the front page of Meta.SE]

What happened here?

Comment: github doesn't have a sticky header, so they're not following github this time

Comment: I was thinking something looked odd but couldn't put my finger on it. Argh, never liked the topbar, too black and too many icons pushed at opposite ends. We are the 1% (wild guess) who had disabled the sticky bar from the beginning and then clean forgot about it.

Comment: July 12 2018: [EDIT I have discovered that I can unstick the sticky bar. Yesss.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311213/can-i-please-have-the-option-to-sticky-my-top-bar-wherever-i-want?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1022630_311213) and *“I know that users tend to dislike new features, and changes take time to get used to. But for me having that black top bar follow me whenever I scroll down is unnerving and reeks of narcissism. I don't need my avatar to shadow me, and the icons on the far left side are not that important.”*