# Why is the link to "help" present in the site switcher and also as a separate option?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, design, top-bar

The new top bar is live. The site switcher and the other options have been moved to the right side. As a part of the new design, the link to the help center is newly added beside chat and log out. [image]

But the same link is also present in the drop down menu of "help center and resources".

[image]

Why is the same link added both in the site switcher and also in help and resources menu?. Isn't this a waste of space? Why is this newly added in the site switcher?

<sub>The same link also appears in the footer. So, it appears thrice on the same page.</sub>

Comment: When you will hit 500 rep, the help icon will be replaced with a review queue icon (as you will gain access to review queues at that point). May still want to access help at that point.

Comment: I will add - why do you think redundancy in UI is a bad thing?

Comment: @Oded Thanks. I don't know it will be changed to review option. Now I understand. I didn't understand why the same link was placedmore than once. I thought a link to some other frequently visited feature would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one in the top bar for the benefit of new users.  New users might not have discovered the site switchers and the treasures it holds, but they'll see a "?" icon and -- ideally -- click on it.  It disappears at 500 rep.

The one in the site switcher is for everybody.  Even experienced users refer to the help sometimes.  I do it often to get links to leave in comments for newer users, for example.

Keeping it out of the site switcher until you reach 500 rep and the icon in the top bar goes away would be weird.  There's no harm, and there is benefit in consistency, to having it in the site switcher for everybody.

Comment: At least something about this design makes sense.

Comment: Yes. If it's was only in the site switcher for users with over 500 reputation, the low-reputation users would never see it there and know where to find it later on.