# Odd red SE logo in new top bar

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

My question is related to [New top bar is coming to the Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network/300831#300831) and also mentioned in the heading, [Clickable Stack Exchange logo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/new-top-bar-is-live). The  **SE logo**, which is now on the left-hand side, was light blue on every site I visited yesterday.

While the logo on IPS (Interpersonal Skills) has not changed colour,

[image]

on EL&U (English Language & Usage) it is an ominous red colour when I visited the site today

[image]

It's creepy, and I admit, it's freaking me out. Is this a feature? What does it mean? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. I have pushed a fix internally, and now waiting for the next build for the fix to be published across the network.

Should be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) in couple hours.

Comment: in "repo" what's that? So, it's a feature by design? Is it? Well, I don't like it, it looks like something from a horror movie. It's creepy! :(

Comment: @Mari-LouA sorry, I wasn't clear enough: it is now fixed in our development environment so you should be able to see normal colors for logo in couple hours (it usually takes some time before change is visible on site).

Comment: @Mari-LouA I took the liberty to edit and explain this better for non programmers.

Comment: So, the colors will be gone after few hours?

Comment: @Sinister correct.

Comment: @Paweł just curious, what caused this?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd SVG inherited color of `a` parent element. We have special helper for inserting SVGs into our code. Usually those SVGs are black, and color is defined by CSS (useful for glyph icons). In some cases, SVGs have native colors (like SE logo) and we don't want them to inherit parent element's color. So we have special modifier for our helper to use SVG's native colors – and that was missing for some reason.

Comment: @Paweł When [rpg.se] loaded up with [an orange logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls7Er.png) this morning I thought it was a Halloween thing. :)

Comment: I don't understand which part was a bug and which was by design. Is the whole idea of making the color change on hover a bug? Or is it supposed to change color and the bug was in the implementation? Does this bug report also cover [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301952/203101)? Or are there separate issues?

Comment: @doppelgreener odd, I'm getting a 503 on that image link (but not on other images on i.stack.imgur).

Comment: "in the repo" - shockingly SE dosen't develop on a live webpage <s> - they push code to a repository (like git), then push to a test instance, then here... With lots of moving bits in between ;)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek i just use notepad.exe for editing files and upload them via FTP Total Commander.

Comment: ... hardcore. To production? ;p

Comment: Aww that red color was nice

Comment: @JourneymanGeek hardcore would be editing the files with notepad on the production server. That is also much quicker as you skip the FTP step ...

Answer (score 6):

The Stack Exchange logo is a link, and without a color of its own, it gets the link color as defined for each site.

The fixed color that was defined for the logo in the beginning has been removed, so that's why we see the default link color. For example here it's blue, on gaming.SE it's dark blue, and on EL&U the color of the links is the red you see.

I do agree it's weird, and better give different color to the logo, but this might as well be by design.

Comment: It was not red on EL&U yesterday. Was it? I'm sure I would have noticed.

Comment: @Mari-LouA nope. Changed just now after the recent outage.

Comment: In [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), by the default the SE logo colour is blue and when we hover over it is red, it purely based on that site's logo.

Comment: "By design" seems a bit strong here. I'll ping folks internally to see if it actually is.

Comment: Super User is an *odd* discordant shade of green.

Comment: They're using the link-color from the site's theme. But they're doing it in a bar that's the same background color across every site, and that's purporting to be the new top bar for all sites. So not only is it pulling a link color that was designed to work as part of a palette other than where it's being used for this, they're breaking the whole "this is the top bar for the whole network" thing to do so.

Comment: @Adam thanks, edited. Still, feels like this was done on purpose.

Comment: Nope, it wasn't done on purpose – it's a bug. Fixing right now.

Comment: @Paweł I keep receiving notifications every time a user posts a comment on Sha Wiz's answer. TBC not under my question. Is this by design or a separate bug?

Comment: @Mari separate bug. But are you sure? Can you post a screenshot first? You should get notification for muru's comment since he pinged you, but not for others.

Comment: Now I got notified because you pinged me that makes sense. But when different users were posting comments to you, I also received a notification.

Comment: @Mari-LouA should not happen, if you take screenshot of your notifications which include comments you shouldn't be notified for (e.g. Arulkumar's, Adam's, etc comments) you can start a new bug report.

Comment: Could you try posting a comment without using my username, because I can't take a screenshot until then.

Comment: Testing a comment without pinging She Who Must Not Be Pinged.

Comment: @muru no, I wasn't pinged. I just happened to check back. Weird, but I was definitely notified previously. Thanks for test driving my observation. I guess there is no bug.