# Please don't red alert me for queues I've handled

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, design, review, top-bar

I have found the [red alert](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355234/3956566) has been helpful in prompting me to review queues.

There should be red when there's red dots against review queues:

[image]
<sub>image stolen from [When I look at the review icon, I see red](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355233/when-i-look-at-the-review-icon-i-see-red)</sub>

However, when I have used all my reviews for some queues:

[image]

If those queues are large enough to warrant the red alert, it will still show on my review icon, even though none of the queues I am able to review in are not alerting.

[image]

It would be better if it is like this:

[image]

Can we have the red alert vanish if the alert is for queues we have finished reviewing for the day please? It's honestly annoying and will eventually degrade the UX for avid reviewers. (*imo*)

Comment: Isn't this fundamentally the same as other FR's regarding showing (or not) things in the review notifications - eg: the functionality has been discussed before re: queues can change size and the number of reviews valid for them change or on review bans etc... It just so happens that it looked one way before but now has a red dot instead...?

Comment: I believe the data for those dots and queue status is not personalized.

Comment: @JonClements we would get a mass of orange numbers yes? Well they've bothered to change it and are trying to improve the UX... so it won't hurt to ask

Comment: @rene I believe you are right. Not sure how hard it would be to implement it hmm

Comment: @YvetteColomb hard as they would need performant review queue queries which atm they are not. So expect more then 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: @Yvette nope - doesn't hurt to ask. I just have a feeling this has been asked before (if not more than once) about the functionality of the review queue indicator - the fact it looks different doesn't really alter that... Besides - I believe they're focusing on the new icon after the recent poll...

Comment: @rene well no harm in asking and we can get it on their to do list :D *ever the optimist*

Comment: @JonClements new icon?

Comment: See: [Review queue updates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357621/review-queue-updates) (MSO)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network/300864#300864 which Team DAG said they're already reviewing in [New top bar is live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/new-top-bar-is-live).

Comment: While this has already been mentioned in an answer (see prior comment by TylerH), it is quite important. Such indicators should only be shown to a user when *that user* can do something about it. Having the "danger indicator" shown when the user can't do anything about it just reinforces the behavior to ignore the indicator, which is directly opposite to the desired behavior. We want users to be reviewing more. That's the purpose of the "danger indicator". Having it shown when that user can't do anything about the "danger" is counterproductive.

Comment: @Makyen I totally agree. It's a disincentive to actually pay attention to it.

Comment: @rene And I guess it would be computationally expensive to do so, which was presumably why SE never fixed the inaccurate numbers on the old review queue display.

Comment: @DavidPostill that is possible but I tried to argue that on other posts a while back and was told by other members I interpreted the discussion I had with Shog9 about this wrongly so I stopped speculating about it.

Comment: @rene Do you have a link to that discussion with shog9?

Comment: @DavidPostill the most recent one was [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6120554#6120554) but it is a returning theme in the Tavern.

Comment: We’ve reviewed this request are moving it to our backlog. I’ve updated the status to status-deferred.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) We are investigating a variety of changes to make this work better for users in different states, including when you run out of reviews.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I saw you had to put in a suggested edit.  Kind of funny. You are now 5 short of writing unreviewed edits.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I'm going to come by it honestly.

Comment: Few months later, any updates on this?

Comment: @ShadowWizard No current plans to enhance this.

Comment: I see a red dot on `Close Votes` even though that I have 0 reviews in the queue.

Comment: Please also see [Review queue showing review alert for users who can't review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389434/review-queue-showing-review-alert-for-users-who-cant-review) (MSO)

Comment: Status deferred. For seven years. I'm guessing this isn't a high priority item.