# Following up issues that former employees were handling

Tags: discussion, support, user-interface, stack-exchange-team, communication

I was led into a trail of investigation into a UI issue from this post on Meta Stack Overflow [Review queue showing review alert for users who can't review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389434/review-queue-showing-review-alert-for-users-who-cant-review), that led me to this post [Please don't red alert me for queues I've handled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302093/please-dont-red-alert-me-for-queues-ive-handled).

I left a comment under the answer to get the attention of the employee, as the post is tagged [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) and realised [the person](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/354333/joe-friend) no longer works for Stack Overflow.

A current employee would get the ping and there'd be some type of ensured communication that the issue will be followed up. How do we go about making these types of "edit" or "updated" communications on posts where the employee has since left the site?

Comment: I'd follow the same tips as [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](/a/306398).

Comment: Just assume updates will appear in 6 to 8 weeks and be done with it ...

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange

Comment: Or ping ab employee in chat, although they might dislike you for doing so.

Comment: Presumably - since I doubt SE isn't an internal dystopia, it ought to have gotten handed over to his successor. Asking about what to do seems like a reasonable way to get attention to it.

Comment: @Luuklag that's not helpful, as in this case the employee has left the site :)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yes, I guess another way of looking at this question - is there a way to map these posts to their successors? Or a way for users to know who to turn to. There's needs to be some type of public workflow that we can follow as users. imo

Comment: Probably no - in theory the old staff page would work but I only know Megan's the PM in question cause of gossip

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yep and I wouldn't want to ping her about it. It would be good to have a system. I forgot Joe even left

Comment: @YvetteColomb, ping a current employee, and ask them if it is on "the schedule"

Comment: @Luuklag enough current employees read this site that it *should* filter through

Comment: Seems like whatever you did worked; another employee has changed the status tag on it.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog chatting in the mod chatroom on SO - but that doesn't help the regular Joe (that's intended - as Joe left)

Comment: FWIW, I got pinged in comments a couple of times since I left, and I generally at least let the commenter know that they're no longer talking to someone official.