# Move mod menu with the other menus

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, moderator-tools, top-bar

Now that all the menus seem to be migrating to a row of icons in the top right, the mod menu feels out of place. May I suggest:

[image: I LIKE MY TOP BAR LIKE I LIKE MY COFFEE, WITH GOOD STRUCTURE]

<sup>* Exact place arrow is pointing not important</sup>

Comment: [It was over there originally.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343316/flag-count-disappears-after-closing-the-moderator-inbox) Nobody liked that position.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

This is the way it was initially and we specifically requested that it be moved to where it is so that it stands out from the rest of the icons and so that the right-most icons are identical on all sites.

This was specifically requested in [Monica's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300834/284336) on the initial announcement question and is the highest-voted post there.

> In the new design, I have to look all the way to the right -- the hardest place to casually view other than the bottom of a window, from what I've heard UX folks say -- and I have to disambiguate a jumble of stuff. Some of that stuff might get clipped, too, judging from my experience on SO.
>
> **Request:** please put all of: flag count, diamond menu, and "mod" link near the center. Either shrink the big search box or drop my badges to make room (gravatar and rep are enough to convey "me").
>
> This isn't about aesthetics or moved cheese. This is about being able to moderate efficiently.

Now, granted, you're not asking them to be moved all the way back to the left, but I really don't want them hidden in the middle of all of the other icons.

They're clear and obvious where they are and I'd prefer they stay where they are.

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of reasons to want that icon to be separate from the rest *and* farther left.

Answer (score 6):

No!

Please just no.

I could cite countless MSE posts with deep discussion on the importance from both a UX and technical perspective on where the mod diamond dropdown should go. (And I might amend this answer later to add some links.) Let's not go over or through all that again, please.