# Review queue buttons aren't visible, can't be scrolled to when browser is less than full screen width (Chrome/Chromium)

Tags: bug, status-planned, review

Since the redesign, I have a problem. I use Chrome on Linux principally, and can test on Windows and OS X if desired. I use the browser window at less than full screen size because I have other small windows open.

With the old design, all was well. But with the new design, when I review the review queues, most of the buttons to click are off the screen. Only the left-most one is on screen. There is no scroll bar on the bottom to scroll over (and I shouldn't have to scroll anyway; the old design didn't require it). I have to put the browser into full-screen mode to make the buttons reappear.

I hope this is the correct place to post this. :)

Comment: I can sort of reproduce (Windows 10, Chrome 71.0.3578.98). Looks like the site width is 1280px in Review, and it doesn't autosize for anything lower. However, I have a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @TheWanderer I tested on Chrome on Win10 at work this morning, and get the same behaviour as you do, with a scroll bar.  Still inconvenient.  Review should autosize.  The lack of a scroll bar may be a Chromium bug (I use the open-source version at home on Linux).

Comment: Is this the same issue as [Can't see all the options while reviewing with a small screen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307976/289905)?

Answer (score -5):

Short answer: we're on it!

Long answer: it won't be done by tomorrow, but it will be done! This has been a known issue for a bit, unfortunately. Making all of our pages responsive is a big priority for the team in general and we're going through page by page to make the difference. Review queues are an important place to do this because, of course, we want to make the process as easy as possible. Better community tools = better community, usually.

Comment: Can you please give this a [tag:status-planned] tag?

Comment: Done. 9 more to go...

Comment: So 6 to 8 weeks?

Comment: @awizardarachnid lol