# Why is there an Ubuntu contact link in the contact pages of many SE sites?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, contact

This might be related to the cause of the issue: [Change the links in Ask Ubuntu contact page](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19702)

---

I visited [MSE's "Contact" page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) and noticed this:

[image: Screenshot of https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact, with "Ubuntu Contact" circled]

Why is there an Ubuntu contact link in MSE's "Contact" page?

It's also there in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/contact), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/contact), [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/contact), etc.

Please update the contact page.

---

Also please change these in contact pages of all SE sites:

- Yahoo link (from https://help.yahoo.com/kb/helpcentral to https://help.yahoo.com/kb/account)
- Google link (from http://www.google.com/contact/ to https://about.google/contact-google/) [HTTP ]

Comment: I don’t quite see the problem. If Facebook, Yahoo, and Google, then why not Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't think the Ubuntu link was there initially in the contact pages of MSE, Mathematics, SO, etc. I guess this is how the contact page looked in past: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqOEu.png.

Comment: The Ubuntu Contact link won't be very useful anyway - at the end of the rabbit hole it's just a marketing page really

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since repetition builds memory, I've been poking at this since your [first](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19702/change-the-links-in-ask-ubuntu-contact-page) and [second](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19826/change-the-links-in-ask-ubuntu-meta-contact-page) requests about it came up on AU meta.

We definitely don't want to keep around outdated links, though they do immediately redirect in all cases, so it's not particularly concerning (unless I'm missing something). That said, there were a variety of things on this page that I felt could be updated - not the least of which is the instructions on how to find the child metas for the sites, which clearly hadn't been updated since we switched to icons in the top bar... in [September of 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network).

Aaron was kind enough to get me a .png of the help icon and so I've updated the wording along with the links.

[image: A screenshot of the updated contact page content with the text "If you have a question about a Stack Exchange site, the best place to ask is on Meta Stack Exchange or the site's own meta - which is in the top bar under the Help icon.." where "help icon" is a question mark inside a circle.]

As to why we link to the Ubuntu Contact specifically, which does seem somewhat out of place next to the other three - [rene's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372047) is a big part of that, though animuson doesn't handle those tickets any more. The general reason that any link is on that page is to try and redirect a large amount of incoming requests that don't relate to Stack Exchange at all.

Now that Slate and Vanny are handling this, we may come up with an updated list of links but I'm loathe to remove one that may be reducing the work they're having to do by intercepting requests about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 10):

Many users assume they can use the Contact Us page for any problem they encounter on the internet, including problems with Facebook, Google, Yahoo and Ubuntu.

Stack Exchange only has (give or take) the awesome Animuson to handle tickets that spawn from the contact us page. Those links are the last resort to redirect lost users to better places, but foremost away from the overloaded SE helpdesk so Stack Exchange staff can spend their valuable time on responding to requests that are indeed meant for Stack Exchange.

The other mentioned  and linked companies have way more capacity to handle the users that follow the links to get help.

If anything, that page needs more links, not less.

Comment: Hmm... Animawesome? Animuwesome?